MongooseServerSelectionError. Mongoose express backend failing to connect to MongoDB
I am making a full stack application with React and Express backend with a MongoDB and I can't seem to connect to my database in my server.js file.
Using the same URI that is in my .env I am able to connect via MongoDB Compass so I do not think the problem is my IP as the error message suggests.
Here is the full error message
MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. 
Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/security-whitelist/
    at _handleConnectionErrors (C:\Users\evanf\Documents\projects\BartenderWebsite\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:909:11)
    at NativeConnection.openUri (C:\Users\evanf\Documents\projects\BartenderWebsite\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:860:11) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
    servers: Map(3) {
    'name of address' => ServerDescription {
      address: 'name of address',
      type: 'Unknown',
      hosts: [],
      passives: [],
      arbiters: [],
      tags: {},
      minWireVersion: 0,
      maxWireVersion: 0,
      roundTripTime: -1,
      minRoundTripTime: 0,
      lastUpdateTime: 771190951,
      lastWriteDate: 0,
      error: [MongoNetworkError],
      topologyVersion: null,
      setName: null,
      setVersion: null,
      electionId: null,
      logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
      primary: null,
      me: null,
      '$clusterTime': null
    },
    'name of address' => ServerDescription {
      address: 'name of address',
      type: 'Unknown',
      hosts: [],
      passives: [],
      arbiters: [],
      tags: {},
      minWireVersion: 0,
      maxWireVersion: 0,
      roundTripTime: -1,
      minRoundTripTime: 0,
      lastUpdateTime: 771191064,
      lastWriteDate: 0,
      error: [MongoNetworkError],
      topologyVersion: null,
      setName: null,
      setVersion: null,
      electionId: null,
      logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
      primary: null,
      me: null,
      '$clusterTime': null
    },
    'name of address' => ServerDescription {
      address: 'name of address',
      type: 'Unknown',
      hosts: [],
      passives: [],
      arbiters: [],
      tags: {},
      minWireVersion: 0,
      maxWireVersion: 0,
      roundTripTime: -1,
      minRoundTripTime: 0,
      lastUpdateTime: 771190960,
      lastWriteDate: 0,
      error: [MongoNetworkError],
      topologyVersion: null,
      setName: null,
      setVersion: null,
      electionId: null,
      logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
      primary: null,
      me: null,
      '$clusterTime': null
    }
  },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: 'atlas-dqamup-shard-0',
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined
}
[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart

and here is the code block that actually attempts to connect to the database
// Express app
const app = express()

// Middleware to parse JSON
app.use(express.json())

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI)
    .then(() => {
        // Listen for requests
        app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
            console.log('Connected to DB & listening on port 4000!')
            })
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    })

I've tried putting the raw env.MONGO_URI text in there and got the same error
I've put the same Mongo_URI but with a messed up username and password and get the same error
I've put the same Mongo_URI but with a messed up db name and I get a different error
I've tried connecting to a local MongoDB that I made myself and get the same error
I've tried setting up the MongoDB to accept all IPs and got the same error
I've updated my Mongo

There is a lot of detail hidden behind [ServerDescription] can you get it to expand that part of the error message?

Can you connect with other tools, e.g. Mongo Shell mongosh?

@Joe Expanded the [ServerDescription]s, but replaced the address with 'name of address'

@WernfriedDomscheit yes I can connect via mongosh just fine

Likewise with [MongoNetworkError]
